# なぜかirbを動かすと(Ignoring jaro_winkler-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built.)と表示される

Tags: ruby, linux, fedora, irb

irbを動かすとなぜか`Ignoring jaro_winkler-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine jaro_winkler --version 1.5.2)`というメッセージが表示されます。なお`gem pristine jaro_winkler --version 1.5.2`をsudoを通して実行して再起動しましたが解決には至っていません. この場合どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

**追記:できる限りの詳細**
恐らくこのパッケージはatomのオートコンプリート用にインストールした`ruby-solargraph`の依存関係パッケージとしてインストールされたようです.このパッケージはFedoraのバージョン29の時まで正常に動作していました.つまり30にアップグレードしてから動作になくなりました.恐らくエラーを吐いている`jaro_winkler`が原因だと思います.`ruby-solargraph`は`apm`でインストールしました.現時点で確認できているだけでこのエラーはirbを動かした時と`bundler`を動かした時に表示されるようです.

**さらに追記**
`$HOME/.gem/ruby/gems`を調べてみた所`jaro_winkler`は入っていました.試しにroot権限でirbを実行してみた所エラーは表示されませんでした.恐らくユーザー側の問題かとは思いますが,解決までには至っていません.

OS:Fedora30
マシン:ThinkPad X280
Ruby:ruby 2.6.3p62

Comment: 情報が少なすぎて解答が付かないと思います。jaro_winklerを新規に入れたのか？それとも過去に正常動作していたのか？irbを実行したときのエラーメッセージは記載されてる内容だけだったの？指定されたコマンドを実行したときのエラーメッセージとか表示されなかった？など、ぱっと見でそのくらいの情報は欲しいと思います。自分では要らない情報だと思っても、有識者から見たら有用な情報ってこともあります。質問をする手間を惜しんでは、所望の解答はつかないと思います。書ける情報はしっかり書きましょう。

Comment: 各gemはどのようにインストールしましたか? bundlerは関係していませんか?

Comment: なお、jaro_winkler は、直接使うよりも rubocop の依存物として間接的にインストールされていることも多いので、 rubocop のインストール経緯も関係するかもしれません。

Comment: すみませんでした,私の伝える力が不足していました.`jaro_winkler`は恐らくatomの`ruby-solargraph`を入れた時の依存関係でインストールされたようです.`ruby-solargraph`は`apm`でインストールしました.過去には正常に動作していました.irbを実行した時のエラーメッセージはこれ単体で,他には出てきていません.bundlerは関係していないと思います.尚これが直接関係しているかまでは定かではありませんが`ruby-solargraph`が正常に機能していません.

Comment: 追記:`ruby-solargraph`はvscode,atom用のオートコンプリートです.

Answer (score 0):

なんとか自力で解決できたのでログを残しておきます.

**解決に至った経緯**
まずビルドが完了していないとの事なので`$HOME/.gem/ruby/gems`の`jaro_winkler`を強引に手動でビルドした所解決しました. なおオートコンプリートの復旧までは残念ながらできませんでした.